# MySQL Prepared Statement Join Query

Tags: php, prepared-statement, left-join

Hello all i have the following tables;

Table - posts

```
PostId,
Email,
ForumId
DatePosted,
Likes,
Dislikes
```

Table - forum

```
ForumId,
ForumTitle,
ForumPostText,
PostDate,
Views
```

I am wanting to pull most information from the '`posts`' table and the forumTitle from the '`forum`' table, both tables share forumId. This will allow the user of a certain email address to see which forum they have posted on. I do not have a great deal of experience with MySQL joins  any help greatly appreciated.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(" SELECT posts.PostId, posts.Email, posts.ForumId, forum.ForumId, forum.ForumTitle FROM posts LEFT JOIN forum ON forum.ForumId = posts.ForumId WHERE posts.Email = ?  ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $usr);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ForumId,$DatePosted,$Likes,$Dislikes,$Title);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the self join

```
SELECT posts.PostId, posts.Email, posts.ForumId, forum.ForumId, forum.ForumTitle 
FROM posts,
forum 
WHERE 
forum.ForumId = posts.ForumId 
AND 
posts.Email = ?
```

Comment: This is called inner join between two tables and not self join.